# 8.14.4: Summing Grid CodeHS

Tags: javascript

Here's the problem:
(This is JavaScript)

Write a function called

function sumGrid(grid)
that takes a grid as a parameter and fills each location in the grid with the sum of the row index and column index of that location.

For example, this code:

```
var grid = new Grid(2, 3);
println(sumGrid(grid));
```

Should output:

```
0   1   2
1   2   3
```

Here's what I got so far...

```
function start(){
   var grid = new Grid(2, 3);
   println(sumGrid(grid));

}
function sumGrid(grid){
   for(var row = 0; row < grid.numRows(); row++){
      for(var col = 0; col < grid.numCols(); col++){
        var elem = (row);
        row += 1;
        print(elem + " ");
    }
        println("");
    col = 0
    for(var row = 0; row < grid.numRows(); row++){
        col += 1;
        var elem2 = (col);
        print(elem2 + " ");
        
      }
   }
}
```

When I run the code it displays:

```
 0   1   2
 1   2  undefined
```

Any idea what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing `undefined` is because you are `print`ing the `sumGrid` function, which doesn't return anything, hence why `undefined` is printed.

Not sure why you have 3 `for` loops there but you only need 2. First loop through the `rows`, then the `cols` and then a simple print of `row + col` should work.

```js
const Grid = function (x, y) {
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
  
  this.numRows = () => {
    return this.x
  }
  
  this.numCols = () => {
    return this.y
  }    
}

const sumGrid = (grid) => {
   for(let row = 0; row < grid.numRows(); row++){
      document.write("<p> ")
      for(let col = 0; col < grid.numCols(); col++){        
        document.write(row + col)
      }
      document.write(" </p>")
    }
}

const grid = new Grid(4, 5)
sumGrid(grid)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work after I looked up the [Grid Documentation](https://static.codehs.com/gulp/720b5d6e105c88ab9af5b4ac2caa045d760d1ef7/jsdoc/chs-js-lib/Grid.html) and used the [Source Code](https://static.codehs.com/gulp/720b5d6e105c88ab9af5b4ac2caa045d760d1ef7/jsdoc/chs-js-lib/graphics_grid.js.html) to practice. I also have it on a [REPL](https://repl.it/join/uxlweviv-paultaylor2)

```
function start(){
  var grid = new Grid(2, 3);
  println(sumGrid(grid));
}
function sumGrid(grid){
  grid.grid.forEach(a=>a.fill(1)) //if some strange error happens, change this line to: grid.forEach(a=>a.fill(1))
  var ans=[]
  var x=grid.toList()
  x.forEach(a=>ans.push(a[0]+a[1]))
  return ans
}
start()
```

Answer (score 0):

It was glitching for me but I got this simpler answer.

```
    function start(){
        var grid = new Grid(2,3);
        println(sumGrid(grid));
    }

    function sumGrid(grid){
        for(var row = 0; row < grid.numRows(); row++){
            for(var col = 0; col < grid.numCols(); col++){
                var elem = col + row;
                grid.set(row, col, elem);
            }
        }
        return grid;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work! This is what I did to get the right output:

```
function start(){
    var grid = new Grid(2, 3);
    println(sumGrid(grid));

}
function sumGrid(grid){
    for(var row = 0; row < grid.numRows(); row++){
        for(var col = 0; col < grid.numCols(); col++){
            var elem = (row);
            row += 1;
            print(elem + " ");
        
    }
    println("");
    col = 0
    for(var row = 0; row < grid.numRows(); row++){
        col += 1;
        var elem2 = (col);
        print(elem2 + " ");
        elem2 += 1
    }
    return elem2
   }
}
```

It may not be the best way to solve it but it gets the job done.